# Cannot enable Mac OSX Lion Location Services with Safari

Tags: macos, safari, geolocation, osx-lion

I just hit a frustrating problem while debugging that I am hoping that someone else has encountered...and solved.  I am troubleshooting an app that uses the javascript Geolocation app on OS X Lion.  I have been using Safari and everything was working fine.

After a reboot, Safari reported that access to Geolocation services was denied.  In the Safari preferences, under privacy, the option to "Limit Website Access to Location Services" the setting is indeed set to "Deny without prompting".

The problem is that I cannot seem to enable this setting.  According the Apple doc, you need to first enable location services for the application in the System Settings.  This is under Security and Privacy -> Privacy.  I have seen cases where this is empty and Safari simply doesn't show up.  Finally, after another reboot, Safari.app actually showed up here.  Unfortunately, after enabling Safari here, I still could not enable location services in the Safari settings.  It is almost like the settings are out of sync with each other.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

I just ran into the same issue but found a solution on a [support forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3423801?start=0&tstart=0).

Solution 1:
Cycling "Set timezone automatically using current location" in the Date & Time > Time Zone preference pane fixed my issue. It's possible that a legacy preference left over from my Snow Leopard install was causing a problem there.

Solution 2:
For me, I had to quit the iPhone simulator to toggle the option on.

The second solution did the trick, but maybe only because I tried the first one, uh, first.

Comment: Soon as I quit the iOS Simulator, Safari showed up in the otherwise blank list of apps authorized for location services.

Comment: For me as well. The iPhone Similator seems to be the culprit. I did not try solution 1, only 2.